# AND in Google Sheets to populate a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am placing this formula in cell Q3.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((isblank(Q4:Q))*(isblank(O4:O)=false),(O4:O),,))
```

I want to populate ROW Q cells from data in ROW O if there is not already data in a  the Q cell.

I'm getting this error message;

"Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 4 arguments."

It doesn't seem it should be that difficult to accomplish this task?

Here is a screen shot;

[image]

Comment: you mean like you already have existing data in Q4:Q and only trying to fill the blank cells from column_O?!

Comment: rockinfreakshow, that's correct, I also don't want to overwrite data in column O, just fillin the blank cells

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(Q4:Q)*NOT(ISBLANK(O4:O)),O4:O,))
```

Comment: Z.. unfortunately that did not work, I've added a screen shot for clarity.

Comment: unfortunately what you're trying to do is not possible with a formula. A range can either have a manually entered result or a result generated via a formula, not both.